# Dependence of Events - Proof

Tags: probability, proof-writing, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, independence

I've been learning for my probability exam checking some proofs in book and I found the following question I can't really answer. Any ideas or help?

Let's assume that events $A$ and $B$ are **NOT** independent. Is it possible that $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent?

Comment: Can you define what are $Ac$ and $Bc$?

Comment: @PC1 They are the complementary events of the events $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the events $A^{c}$ and $B^{c}$ are independent, then $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Indeed, suppose that $A^{c}$ and $B^{c}$ are independent:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) & = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cup B^{c})\\\\\
& = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A^{c}) - \mathbb{P}(B^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c})\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(B^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(A^{c})\mathbb{P}(B^{c})\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B^{c})(\mathbb{P}(A^{c}) - 1)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(B^{c})\mathbb{P}(A)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(A)(1 - \mathbb{P}(B^{c}))\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) 
\end{align*}

hence we conclude that $A$ and $B$ are independent. Consequently, the answer to your question is no.

Hopefully this helps!